# Why is setInterval calling a function with random arguments?

Tags: javascript, firefox

So, I am seeing a curious problem. If I have a function

```
// counter wraps around to beginning eventually, omitted for clarity.
var counter; 
cycleCharts(chartId) {
    // chartId should be undefined when called from setInterval
    console.log('chartId: ' + chartId);
    if(typeof chartId == 'undefined' || chartId < 0) {
        next = counter++;
    }
    else {
        next = chartId;
    }
    // ... do stuff to display the next chart
}
```

This function can be called explicitly by user action, in which case `chartId` is passed in as an argument, and the selected chart is shown; or it can be in autoplay mode, in which case it's called by a `setInterval` which is initialized by the following:

```
var cycleId = setInterval(cycleCharts, 10000);
```

The odd thing is, I'm actually seeing the `cycleCharts()` get a `chartId` argument even when it's called from `setInterval`! The `setInterval` doesn't even have any parameters to pass along to the `cycleCharts` function, so I'm very baffled as to why `chartId` is not undefined when `cycleCharts` is called from the `setInterval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setInterval is feeding cycleCharts actual timing data ( so one can work out the actual time it ran and use to produce a less stilted response, mostly practical in animation )

you want

```
 var cycleId = setInterval(function(){ cycleCharts(); }, 10000);
```

( this behavior may not be standardized, so don't rely on it too heavily )

Comment: You're right, but I think he wants this:

     var cycleId = setInterval(function(){ cycleCharts() }, 10000);

Answer (score 3):

It tells you how many milliseconds late the callback is called.

Answer (score 1):

var cycleId = setInterval(cycleCharts, 10000, 4242);

From the third parameter and onwards - they get passed into the function so in my example you send 4242 as the chartId. I know it might not be the answer to the question you posed, but it might the the solution to your problem? I think the value it gets is just random from whatever lies on the stack at the time of passing/calling the method.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, but that doesn't work in IE, and besides, I'm not passing in any additional arguments. Thanks though!